# Android updating custom preference summary

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am using the custom Number Picker Preference from [this Github repo](https://github.com/Alobar/AndroidPreferenceTest). It works well, but I want the summary to show up with the current value. I'm using AndroidStudio's standard settings activity with this. I added the following XML to one of the preference tabs:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <com.example.appname.Settings.NumberPickerPreference
        android:key="key_number"
        android:title="Give me a number"
        android:defaultValue="55" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I added the following else statement to onPreferenceChange:

```
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {

    ...

        } else if(preference instanceof com.example.appname.Settings.NumberPickerPreference){
        preference.setSummary("Test");
        } 

    ...

    }
};
```

I can't get the summary to show up. I can get it to statically to show up if I do it through the XML. Can someone explain how I can get the summary to show up on this custom preference?

Here is the full preference activity I added the above code to:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
/**
 * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
 * to reflect its new value.
 */
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list.
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

            // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
            preference.setSummary(
                    index >= 0
                            ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                            : null);

        } else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
            // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display value
            // using RingtoneManager.
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                // Empty values correspond to 'silent' (no ringtone).
                preference.setSummary(R.string.pref_ringtone_silent);

            } else {
                Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                        preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));

                if (ringtone == null) {
                    // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
                    preference.setSummary(null);
                } else {
                    // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone display
                    // name.
                    String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
                    preference.setSummary(name);
                }
            }

        } else if(preference instanceof com.example.appname.Settings.NumberPickerPreference){

            preference.setSummary("Test");

        } else {
            // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
            // simple string representation.
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
        return true;
    }
};

/**
 * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
 * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
 */
private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
}

/**
 * Binds a preference's summary to its value. More specifically, when the
 * preference's value is changed, its summary (line of text below the
 * preference title) is updated to reflect the value. The summary is also
 * immediately updated upon calling this method. The exact display format is
 * dependent on the type of preference.
 *
 * @see #sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
 */
private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();
}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        if (!super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item)) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
    return isXLargeTablet(this);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
}

/**
 * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
 * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
 */
protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
    return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || GeneralPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || DataSyncPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || NotificationPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
}

/**
 * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/**
 * This fragment shows notification preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class NotificationPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_new_message_ringtone"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/**
 * This fragment shows data and sync preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class DataSyncPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_data_sync);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("sync_frequency"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've never set the change listener on your preference using `preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(...)` (or, in your code, I guess it would be `bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(preference)`)